# htaccess rewrite to https except for few pages and files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I use htaccess file to rewrite some url's and also to rewrite http requests to https:

```
# No Caching for page files
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
</filesMatch>

# Error pages
ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/#/404
ErrorDocument 500 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/#/500

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R,L]

# Rewrite http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/tvgids\/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Ignore conditions for files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteBase /

# Rewrite /api to api.php
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ api/api.php [QSA,L]

# Rewrite /tvgids to guide/index.php
RewriteRule ^tvgids/(.+)$ guide/index.php [QSA,L]

# Rewrite /tv to m3u/index.php
RewriteRule ^tv/(.+)$ m3u/index.php [QSA,L]

# Rewrite /get to get/index.php
RewriteRule ^get/(.+)$ get/index.php

# Rewrite /downloads to downloads.php
# RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ download/download.php [QSA,L]
```

But the rewrite condition for /tvgids doesnt work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/tvgids\/
```

Instead if i try to enter /tvgids/abc i get a 404.

I need all pages to rewrite to https, except for a few pages because they are used in apps on android which do not support https.

Can anyone help me with this - now i have to disable ssl for all pages because else nothing works. I dont see what i am doing wrong, is the condition not set right?

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(tvgids\/.*|tv\/.*|get\/.*|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.ico)$ [NC]
```

which also redirects me to https.. but if i test it here:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

It does work -- so am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working with this code:

```
# Rewrite http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(/tvgids/|/tv/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

the `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/tvgids/ [NC]` sets a condition where no redirecting to https will be done when tvgids/ is the request. And i didnt need to exclude image file types because i already set a condition to exclude folders and files..